# PyAutoGui dosnt start typing when compiled with py2app

Tags: python, python-3.x

it just dosnt. it asks me to allow it to control my computer. I allow it. annnnnd....nothing. it doesn't start typing.

command
`python3 setup.py py2app --packages=pyautogui`

setup file

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['spam.py']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': False
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

and yes, I have tried reinstalling all packages

Comment: maybe there is a problem in `spam.py`?

Comment: no, it works fine in the terminal without using py2app to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a limitation of py2app. If I were to compile this for Windows, Linux and Mac, I would use C or Go, maybe even NodeJS and Electron, just not Python. Its great for developer projects and quick programs, not so great for projects were speed matters or commercial projects that you plan to release on GitHub.